# Iterating over XML to a list of dicts

Tags: python, xml, list, dictionary

I have a list:

```
listaderetorno = []
```

And I will fill it with a dictionary, where the values for the keys will be gotten from an XML file:

```
dictDup = {
        'Nota':'',
        '#number':'',
        'Valor':'',
        'Vencimento':''}
```

I want to repeat this dict N times inside the list, according to the number of times a specific element appears in the XML file:

```
#Count how many times the node appears
#On the example the node appears 3x
n_nodes = 0
for n, elem in enumerate(root.iter('{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}Node')):
        listaderetorno.append(dictDup)
        n_nodes = n+1
```

Now I want to fill each dictionary with the elements.text inside each node:

```
for n, elem in enumerate(root.iter('{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}Node')):
        listaderetorno[n]['#number'] = elem.text
```

Instead of filling the values on the keys of each dictionary:

```
elem[0] => listaderetorno[0]['#number']
elem[1] => listaderetorno[1]['#number']
elem[2] => listaderetorno[2]['#number']
```

It's returning all the dicts with the value of the last node only

|  | #number |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 003 |
| 1 | 003 |
| 2 | 003 |

**It should be like this:**

|  | #number |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 001 |
| 1 | 002 |
| 2 | 003 |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are inserting `n` references to same dictionary into a list, so in fact every iteration you are updating same dictionary, which initialized as `dictDup`. If you want to make copies, you can use `listaderetorno.append({**dictDup})`. But generally I see no reason of prefilling list with template dictionaries to add values in loop later, you can make `listaderetorno.append({'Nota': '', '#number': elem.text, 'Valor': '', 'Vencimento': ''})`.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'm still learning.